# Rails authenticate admin for pages -- but allow jquery calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I want to add a private method to LanguagesController :authenticate_admin

Is there a way to only have it run on the pages themselves, but if a jQuery call is made to that controller, it is allowed?

right now I have

```
before_action :authenticate_admin


private
def authenticate_admin
      if current_user.role_id != 1
        redirect_to home_path
      end
end
```

But there is a dropdown of languages on the sign up and user's dashboard. So, in profile,js there is:

```
var getLanguages = $.get('/languages.json', function(languages){
        lang = languages
        var langConfirmSource = $('#language-confirmation-template').html();
        var langConfirmCompiled = Handlebars.compile(langConfirmSource);
        var langConfirmTemplate = langConfirmCompiled(languages)
        $('body').append(langConfirmTemplate)
     });
```

What is the right way to set it to protect admin only on pages, but let jQuery do it's thing when called?

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a page, rendered by a rails application and have your JavaScript code on that page. This page is authenticated and you want to allow an ajax request to be public accessible.

If that is correct, you might want to skip your authentication when a specific request comes in.

So you can create a new route, mapping to your controller method and having a skip_authenticate_admin for that method:

```
class LanguagesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action : authenticate_admin, only: [:languages_whatever]

   def languages_whatever
     render json: data
   end
end
```

does it help?

Comment: I know I can call a controller, but the issue is that you have to have a page associated with it, and that page has to be accessible by everyone. I'm wondering if there is another way to say 'if someone goes to /languages and is not an admin - they are redirected' BUT 'if the app calls /languages from ANY page -- even by a non-admin it's allowed'   is that a thing?

Comment: Are you aware that you don't have to have a page, but also respond with JSON objects, for instance? That's useful to creating APIs. Your request can return a 'view' or a JSON object.

What you want is possible. You can test the user and if it's not an admin just return the JSON. To do so, you can remove your before_action :authenticate_admin and test it in the controller call (I can think of some other ways, but that's simpler now). However, that's not recommended so consider creating a specific route for that.